# Does querySelectorAll support the period(.) character in an id?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

Does querySelectorAll support the period(.) character in an id?

I mean if I append an element like below:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id='my.divid';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

and then I use querySelectorAll like below:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#my.divid');
```

then I get nothing!

So period is legal character for id, and querySelectorAll is the official method which Firefox provided; I can't believe the method doesn't support period(.) in id. Did I make some mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A period in `querySelectorAll` means you are specifying a css class. In your case `querySelectorAll` is trying to find out a DOM element with `id` "my" and having a css class "divid". How will `querySelectorAll` know that this time you want element by id and not by class? It is up to you to have proper `id` atrribute so as to no to confuse the method. Though a period is allowed, the best practise is to avoid it most of the time so that you do not confuse other libraries like jquery etc.

Comment: So it means querySelectorAll does not support period in id attribute? If I want insert period in id, I can't get it by querySelectorAll, or I must change the period(.) in id to backslash and period(\.), is it right?

Comment: You'll have to use "\\." to escape it, I think.

Comment: @user2155362: You must have missed my upvoted answer where I explained basically everything you asked, 10 minutes before you posted your comment.

Comment: I verified double backward slash \\ works .e.g. `querySelector("#abc\\.test");`

Answer (score 45):

You need to remember that `.` represents a class selector, so the selector `#my.divid` represents an element with the ID `my` and a class `divid`, *not* an element with the ID `my.divid`. So, the following element would be matched by your selector:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'my';
div.className = 'divid';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

If you need to select an element with the ID `my.divid` as you have given above, you need to escape the period:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#my\\.divid');
```

Note that the double backslash is because it's a JS selector string; in a CSS rule you would use a single backslash: `#my\.divid`

Comment: Elsewhere, this: newName = CSS.escape("name.dot") returns 'name\\.dot'.  Thanks to  
Mathias Bynens for pointing it out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702301/js-escaping-a-string-with-backslash-at-the-end-of-a-string-for-using-with-jque