# JS: Escaping a string with backslash at the end of a string, for using with jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, escaping

i have a string like "CS5990+-&|!(){}[]^"~*?:\"

I want to use this string as a selector in an expression like

```
$('[data-name="' + string + '"]')
```

where string is the above string.
But sizzle of jquery throws an error because of the last slash.
Is there anyway i can escape this string and still use this string as a selector ?
I tried escape(), but it threw an error. Please help

Answer (score 3):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.
>   - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

For an attribute value in a selector it seems you can get away with just double escaping the backslash and quotation mark e.g.

```
var string = "CS5990+-&|!(){}[]^\\\"\~*?:\\\\";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9PF4G/1/

Here's a function to escape the special characters in a selector:

```
function escapeSelector(selector) {
    selector = selector.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\');
    return selector.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"@!^$[\]()<=>|\/\{\}\?])/g,'\\$1');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9PF4G/5/

Comment: That will escape the string, but will the selector still work with the escaped string?

Comment: It should do, try the jsfiddle

Comment: Please use the standard `CSS.escape` or [its polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape) instead of inventing custom logic that deviates from the spec.

Comment: The docs still say CSS.escape is experimental.

Answer (score 1):

The given code snippet is problematic:

```
$('[data-name="' + string + '"]');
```

The variable part is `string`. It helps to assume this is user-controlled input. (It may not be for your specific use case, but the solution to your problem is the same regardless, and thinking about it this way makes the dangers of not solving this properly more clear.)

Imagine what happens if `string` contains `"`, e.g. `string === 'foo"bar'`.  This would produce `[data-name="foo"bar"]`, breaking out of the attribute selector, likely breaking the whole CSS selector and resulting in an exception being thrown.

Worse, imagine what happens if `string` is a carefully crafted value like `'"], #my-evil-selector, [x="'`. In that case, we get:

`[data-name=""], #my-evil-selector, [x=""]`

In other words, the selector now likely selects a completely different element than what you intended. This could be a security issue!

The solution is two-fold:

1. Wrap `string` in a call to `CSS.escape`. No matter which string value `string` holds, `CSS.escape(string)` always produces a valid CSS identifier.
2. Since we now have a valid CSS identifier, we can drop the quotes around the attribute value anymore. (Alternatively, to keep the quotes, you’d have to turn `string` into a valid CSS string literal, which seems more difficult to do for no benefit.)

So the final solution is:

```
$('[data-name=' + CSS.escape(string) + ']');
```

---

**Fun fact:** when inspecting an element in Chrome DevTools, the right-click menu provides a “copy JS path” option which does something very similar to this. It produces a JavaScript snippet of the form:

```
document.querySelector("#foo-bar-baz")
```

…where the ID (or whatever else occurs in the selector) is essentially user-supplied input — it’s provided by the web page!

And guess what? [The old implementation got the escaping wrong](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=930625), producing invalid JavaScript code in some cases, and invalid UTF-8 in others.

[The patch that fixed (and simplified) the code](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1464719) follows the logic I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your '\' and '"' with '\'

```
string = 'CS5990+-&|!(){}[]^\"~*?:\\'
```

Comment: That will escape the string, but will the selector still work with the escaped string?

Comment: Right, double escape is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var string = 'CS5990\\+\\-\\&\\|\\!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\^\\"\\~\\*\\?\\:\\\\';
alert($('#'+string).val());
```