# Escape splash:select query selector within lua code

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I can't figure out the correct way to escape the periods in `splash:select`

I have a splash request in scrapy that is using lua to wait for a specific element. This element is an id with periods in the id. I can't seem to correctly escape the periods. I have tried both single and double backslashes (`\` and `\\`)

```
lua_script = '''
    function main(splash)
        splash:set_user_agent(splash.args.ua)
        assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
        while not splash:select('div#some.id.here') do
            splash:wait(0.1)
        end
        return {html=splash:html()}
    end
'''
```

Expected result is the fully loaded html from the requested page

Actual result is:

```
WARNING: Bad request to Splash: {'description': 'Error happened while executing Lua script', 'error': 400, 'type': 'ScriptError', 'info': {'error': "invalid escape sequence near '\\.'", 'source': '[string "..."]', 'message': '[string "..."]:5: invalid escape sequence near \'\\.\'', 'line_number': 5, 'type': 'LUA_INIT_ERROR'}}
```

When using `\` or `\\`

If I try escape the string inside the `splash:select` as such:

```
splash:select(\'div#some.id.here\')
```

The code continuously runs (I believe this is a step in the right direction, but I think at this stage the code runs correctly but it's trying to find a multi-classed div instead of a div with the ID containing periods)

Comment: why do you have to escape periods? shouldn't you rather escape the single quotes in the Python string?

Comment: @Piglet Due to how `splash:select` works, this code will just run forever (the periods need to be escaped like https://stackoverflow.com/a/17563341/10221271 to my understanding).

I will update my question to include what happens when I escape the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a Python string that contains Lua code.

```
'splash:select(\'div#some.id.here\')'
```

Your splash stuff needs you to escape the `.`

So we need to prepend a backslash.

In order to avoid an invalid escape sequence `\.` error in Lua we have to escape the backslash by prepending another backslash. `\\.`

As we're still in a Pyhton string we have to escape the 2 backslashes again. Resulting in a total of four backslashs.

```
'splash:select(\'div#some\\\\.id\\\\.here\')'
```

Python `'\\\\.'` will be interpreteded as `'\\.'` by Lua which will end up as `'\.'` in your `splash:select` call

I hope this makes sense. I cannot test it.

Comment: This worked :) thank you! The returned html is still wrong, but I think that's for different reasons which I'll make a new question for